# JPA problem @OneToMany - how to get particular objects from database?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have `User` and `Series` entities. An user has list of series.

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private List<Series> series = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="series")
public class Series {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String year;
    private String photo; //as an url
    private String description;
    private float totalScore;
    private float score;

    User user;
}
```

I want to get series which are assign to particular user.
In the Series service, I do something like this to get series:

```
@Override
public List<Series> getAllSeries() {
    return seriesRepository.findAll();
}
```

But I get all series from database. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Should I pass the user in the request?

Comment: What is the column name for the foreign key of User in the `Series` entity? can you provide a `Series` entity, as well as your repository interface?

Comment: I edited my post :D

Comment: findAll() will return all the series available in the database. You need to pass some input to get the desired result set. Utilize the JPA methods like `findByUser(String user)`.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri JpaRepository

Comment: @Sofija did it help? you solved your problem?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Yes, I think it will work now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting *series*, because you query the Series Repository, with *findAll()*.

If you want to get *Series*, which belong to the particular user, just pass the userId to the corresponding method, like:

```
@Override
public List<Series> getSeriesByUserId(int userId) {
   return seriesRepository.findByUserId(userId);
}
```